# How to check the difference between two "web.config" files

Tags: powershell

I'd like to check the difference between two "web.config" files. How is that possible with Powershell?

Comment: How would you like to work with the difference? Work with it in a script? Or just visual comparison is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Compare-Object as follows:

```
clear-host
$strFile1 = get-Content "C:\config_files_1\web.config"
$strFile2 = get-Content "C:\config_files_2\web.config"
Compare-Object $strFile1 $strFile2
```

For further information, you may be interested in checking out the following article:

- [Compare-Object to Find the Differences Between Files](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_compare_object.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a semantic comparison, look at: 
https://github.com/CameronWills/FatAntelope 
This tool will compare web.config files and generate a web.config transform from the difference. And it can be run from the command line.

Disclaimer: I wrote it.

Comment: Can you provide some example code (for powershell) and maybe some screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

This PowerShell script tells you which app settings keys are missing from one or the other, maybe you could tailor to your needs?

```
[xml]$file1 = Get-Content "C:\web.config1"
[xml]$file2 = Get-Content "C:\web.config2"
Compare-Object ($file1.SelectNodes("//add[@key]") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Key) ($file2.SelectNodes("//add[@key]")  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Key)
```